# matching two chars with multiple lines in between

Tags: regex, perl

I am new to regex and I am using Perl.

I have below tag:

```
<CFSC>cfsc_service=TRUE
SEC=1
licenses=10
expires=20170511
</CFSC>
```

I want to match anything between `<CFSC>` and `</CFSC>` tags.

I tried `/<CFSC>.*?\n.*?\n.*?\n.*?\n<\/CFSC>/`
and `/<CFSC>(.*)<\/CFSC>/` but had no luck.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and the Perl tag. Please take a moment to take the [tour] to learn how to use this site. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `/s` [single line modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) to make the regex engine include line breaks in `.`.

> Treat string as single line. That is, change "." to match any character whatsoever, even a newline, which normally it would not match.

See this example.

```
my $foo = qq{<CFSC>cfsc_service=TRUE
SEC=1
licenses=10
expires=20170511
</CFSC>};

$foo =~ m{>(.*)</CFSC>}s;

print $1;
```

You also need to use a different delimiter than `/`, or escape it.

Comment: Thanks, i got the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
/<CFSC>(.*)<\/CFSC>/s
```

The final `s` makes the `.` match newline chars (`\n` = 0x0a) which is usually doesn't match:

> Treat string as single line. That is, change "." to match any
>   character whatsoever, even a newline, which normally it would not
>   match.

from http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$foo =~ m/<CFSC>((?:(?!<\/CFSC>).)*)<\/CFSC>/gs;
```

Modifiers:

```
       g - Matches global
       s - newline
       i - case sensitive
       \ - escape sequence
```